# What is the purpose of using unclass() function? and why the error ""the column indexes must be at most 2 if postive,not 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10" appears

Tags: r

What is the purpose of using unclass() function in r ? I can't get it right.
Can you demisifiy it with this code below?

```
unclass(tele%>%mutate(dec=ntile(rev_Range,n=10))%>%count(dec)%>%unname())[[2]]
```

Comment: The docs (`?unclass`) say, "`unclass` returns (a copy of) its argument with its class attribute removed. (It is not allowed for objects which cannot be copied, namely environments and external pointers.)" If your question isn't covered by that, you should include some data that we can use to reproduce what you're asking

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let me try explaining the usage of 'unclass'

Let's suppose you have this vector of colors:

```
cores = c('blue','green','red')
```

And a group of strings stored as factors, for example:

```
val = c('setosa','setosa','virginica','versicolor','virginica','setosa')

val_fac = factor(val)
```

If you apply unclass to this group of factors, unclass will convert the factors to their numbers, like:

```
unclass(val_fac)

[1] 1 1 3 2 3 1
attr(,"levels")
[1] "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica"
```

With these numbers you can convert the factors to colors, by doing:

```
cores[unclass(val_fac)]

[1] "blue"  "blue"  "red"   "green" "red"   "blue"
```

Hope this helps you,

Best regards,

Gustavo,

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer.

Because the statement above return dataframe, and because we return a data frame to variable, it will throw the error "the column indexes must be at most 2 if postive,not 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,so we need to unclass it to convert dataframe to list.

and since the unclass return list so we need [[2]] to access the value of returned list

Answer (score 0):

`Unclass()` is like label encoding in pandas. It just orders categorical data from 1 to n